# PSQL/JPA: rewrite query from returning List<> of occurences to Map<Date, List<>> of Ocurrences per Date

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have a pre-defined query / jpa operation

```
jpaOperations.findByQuery(ActivityCountByCategory.class,
"SELECT NEW ActivityCountByCategory(u.text, count(1)) 
FROM Activity a JOIN a.groupCategories c, UserDefinedCode u 
WHERE (u.id.code = c AND u.id.entityName='AKTOR_AKTIVITET' AND u.id.fieldName='KATEGORI') 
AND a.closedIndicator = 'F' GROUP BY u.text, u.lineNo ORDER BY u.lineNo");
```

that returns a List of DTO's named `ActivityCountByCategory` that contains a name for an Activity and a number representing ocurrences in the DB.
This method thus returns the number of individual Activities for all time.

```
UserDefinedCode
```

The Tables are defined such that the activities reside in `AKTOR_AKTIVITET` and have an ID that is referenced from a second table represented by `UserDefinedCode` so that the Name - part is de-coupled from the Activity.

I need to expand this query so that I can pass a Date fromDate and Date toDate and have it return some form of `List<Object[]>` or `Map<Date, List<ActivityCountByCategory>>` so that instead of returning all occurences at once, I can split the occurrences into individual dates `between fromDate and toDate` and map each return List to one particular Date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote the query in native SQL and edited the DTO to account for Date as well, then did some parsing in the backing bean java code:

```
public List<ActivityCountByCategory> getCreatedUserDefinedActivityCountByDate(Date fromDate, Date toDate) {

        Query query;
        query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT" +
                " trunc(a.dato), fcode.TEXT, COUNT(1) FROM ACTIVITY a INNER JOIN ACTIVITY_CATEGORY act_cat ON a.ID=act_cat.ACTOR_ID INNER JOIN " +
                "user_defined_code fcode ON fcode.kode = act_cat.category where ... " + 
                "AND trunc(a.DATO) BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate GROUP BY trunc(a.dato), fcode.TEXT , fcode.lineNo ORDER BY fcode.lineNo ");
        query.setParameter("fromDate", fromDate);
        query.setParameter("toDate", toDate);

        List<Object[]> resultList = query.getResultList();
        List<ActivityCountByCategory> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Object[] result : resultList) {
            list.add(new ActivityCountByCategory((String) result[1], (Number) result[2], (Date) result[0]));
        }
        return list;
    }
```